# How do I use Leibniz's rule to show find the derivative of $\int_{0}^{x} f(t)x\sin(xt)\, dt$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do I use Leibniz's rule to show find the derivative of $$\int_{0}^{x} f(t)x\sin(xt)\, dt$$ where $f(t)$ is continuous on the interval $[0,b]$ and $b>0$, $0 \le x \le b$. The rule is given as $$\dfrac{d}{dx} \bigg(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} g(x,t)\, dt\bigg) = g(x,b(x))\cdot \dfrac{d}{dx}b(x)-g(x,a(x))\cdot \dfrac{d}{dx}a(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x,t)\,dt$$

Also, I'm not really sure what $g(x,a(x))$ or $g(x,b(x))$ equates to if I let $g(x,t) = f(t)x \sin(xt)$. Do I just plug in $a(x)$ or $b(x)$ in place of $t$ in $g(x,t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you have

$$a(x) = 0 \implies \frac{d}{dx}a(x) = 0 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
$$b(x) = x \implies \frac{d}{dx}b(x) = 1 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Also, as you stated, you have

$$g(x,t) = f(t)x\sin(xt) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

You thus have that

$$g(x,a(x)) = g(x,0) = f(0)x\sin(0) = 0 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$
$$g(x,b(x)) = g(x,x) = f(x)x\sin(x^2) \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x,t) & = f(t)\left(\sin(xt) + x\left(\frac{\partial\sin(xt)}{\partial(xt)}\right)\left(\frac{\partial{(xt)}}{\partial{x}}\right)\right)\\
& = f(t)(\sin(xt) + xt\cos(xt))
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

Now, you can just plug these values into the RHS of your stated rule.